# Adding CorePlot to iPhone Project - Errors?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

[image: Activity view window for project]

Linker information below

[image: deleteTest - deleteTest.xcodeproj]

Followed the directions.

[image: deleteTest - deleteTest.xcodeproj]

Any ideas on how to fix?

Followed directions for install. I'm using Xcode 4.0.

Thanks, J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rechecked instructions and dragged CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj into project properly. Solved the problem. Hope this helps someone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow [the instructions](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications)?  Make sure you add `-ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot` to Other Linker Flags.

Comment: Yes. I believe I did. See additional image above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include Foundation.framework in your "deleteTest" target.  Select it then go to "Build Phases", you will see one of the phases as "Link Binaries and Libraries", expand this and click the + sign in the bottom left of this list.  Add the Framework from this list.

Comment: Kenny, I added a picture of the Link Library above... Foundation is already included. I'm pretty sure this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

There I found a good link for using Core-Plot having detailed explaining how to add it to project & use the delegate method of Core-Plot.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

It worked g8 for me. Hope you would be able to do the same ,yesterday only I did the same thing from here.